# Google forms app script form validation of existing field

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to add a validation into an existing Google Form. I was already able to identify the item ID of the field I want to add a validation. I am just doing first the very basic requireTextContainsPattern in my text validation. I tried to follow https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation

```
 function validationTest() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('formID');
        var item = form.getItemById(itemID);

        var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
          .setHelpText("Enter email address")
          .requireTextContainsPattern("info@example.com")
          .build();
    
         item.setValidation(textValidation);
```

When I debug my code, I am getting

```
TypeError: item.setValidation is not a function
```

My question is: 1) How do I get this textvalidation into my the existing field in Google Form? 2) Is the error I am getting related to my question no. 1? But primarily, I wanted to resolve no. 1.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form.getItemById(id)` returns `Item`. You need to change the reference from `Item` to `TextItem`. To do so you may use the method `asTextItem()` ([see reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#astextitem))

```js
function validationTest() {
  var item = form.getItemById(itemID).asTextItem();
  // [...]
}
```

Note that this will throw an error if `itemID` is not an ID of a text item.

### References

- [Interface Item (Google Apps Script)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item)
- [Class TextItem (Google Apps Script)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item)

Comment: Oh thanks for this. I've actually been putting .asTextItem() here: item.setValidation(textValidation); such that the line is: item.TextItem.setValidation(textValidation);